# intelliJ spring error no creating table users

Tags: mysql, spring, intellij-idea

I am working with Spring and MySQL on a new application. I'm used to working on Spring via the Spring suite of tools. However, for this project I decided to use IntelliJ. I did the classic, created the project via start.spring.io

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.kevi</groupId>
    <artifactId>PortFolio</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>PortFolio</name>
    <description>Presentation of my compétences</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I configured my application.properties file

```
server.port=7070
#jdbc properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/portfolioDatabase?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=zizou123
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
#hibernate properties
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

I created my users entity.

```
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;


import java.io.Serializable;
    @Entity
    @Table(name="users")
    public class User implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long idUser;
        private String lastNameUser;
        private String firstNameUser;

        public User() {

        }
        public User(String lastNameUser, String firstNameUser) {
            this.lastNameUser = lastNameUser;
            this.firstNameUser = firstNameUser;
        }

        public String getLastNameUser() {
            return lastNameUser;
        }

        public String getFirstNameUser() {
            return firstNameUser;
        }

        public void setLastNameUser(String lastNameUser) {
            this.lastNameUser = lastNameUser;
        }

        public void setFirstNameUser(String firstNameUser) {
            this.firstNameUser = firstNameUser;
        }
    }
```

The application launches correctly, the database is created but not the users table. I don't understand why, can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance for your help !

annexed files:

````
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PortFolioApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PortFolioApplication.class, args);
    }

}```
````

Comment: Can you share your full project code on Google Drive or GitHub then I can take a try on it?

Comment: yes no problem, take the link of my drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rs6aGM4vr4q-ehR3UnRUr032_z1faxFf/view?usp=drive_link @JackyLiu-JetBrains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project, '**PortFolioApplication.java**' is in **com.kevi.PortFolio** package. Where as '**User.java**' is in **com.kevin.PortFolio.entities** package.

Here, there is package name difference '**kevi**' for '**PortFolioApplication.java**'. So, Change it to '**kevin**' and run the code. It will work.

Spring Boot @SpringBootApplication annotation also triggers Component Scanning from it's package, which also scans the package **com.kevin.PortFolio.entities**.

Comment: thanks !! sorry for this banality ! @Harshavardhan